# Customizing list shown from SimpleCursorAdapter using ViewBinder

Tags: android, android-listview, customization, simplecursoradapter

I'm building a `ListView` with either `TextView`s or `ImageView`s based on whether or not the item is a text item or has an image associated with it. I used [Customizing list shown from SimpleCursorAdapter using VewBinder](http://enjoyandroid.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/customizing-simple-cursor-adapter/) and it worked great, up to a point.

I have an `SQLite database` containing items that all have a title (some text), but not all of them have an image/video as a resource; so some are pure text items while others are images or videos. For the images and videos I want to load a resource, but when the item is a plain text item, I just want to display the title of the image.

So my `XML` contains two elements - a `TextView` to display the title of the text items, and an `ImageView` to display the resource file (for videos I retrieve the YouTube default image for the video id).

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_details_title"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"  />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_details_resource"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not using a `Content Provider` because I don't need other apps to ever use my database. I use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and have written a `CustomViewBinder` (inner) class to bind my data to my `view`s based on whether or not there is a resource associated to the item.

The problem is that the visibility of the `ImageView` is always set to `GONE` no matter what. So the title of each item is displayed, because that is always bound to the `TextView` element, but when there is no resource listed in my database (i.e. "null" is in the record in the `resource` field), then the `ImageView` also disappears.

Here is the code for my `CustomViewBinder`:

```
private class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder{
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
        if(columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_RESOURCE)){
            Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "columnIndex = " + columnIndex);

            //If the column is resource, ten we use custom view.
            String resource = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "resource = " + resource);

            if(resource.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
                Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "Inside if resource = " + resource);
                Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "Set the image view to GONE");
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "Inside else resource = " + resource);
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_TITLE);
                Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "columnIndex = " + columnIndex);

                //If the column is resource, ten we use custom view.    
                String title = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "title = " + title);

                if(!resource.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
                    Log.d("CustomViewBinder", "Set the title view to GONE");
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And then some logs for clarity:

```
07-26 17:05:36.343: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 4
07-26 17:05:36.343: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.343: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Inside if resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.343: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Set the image view to GONE
07-26 17:05:36.353: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 4
07-26 17:05:36.353: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.353: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Inside if resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.353: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Set the image view to GONE
07-26 17:05:36.363: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 4
07-26 17:05:36.363: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.363: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Inside if resource = null
07-26 17:05:36.363: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Set the image view to GONE
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 4
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): resource = Notes_Box_2_Notebook_1_006.jpg
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Inside else resource = Notes_Box_2_Notebook_1_006.jpg
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 2
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): title = Notebook page - man and wife
07-26 17:05:53.770: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Set the title view to GONE
07-26 17:05:54.310: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): columnIndex = 4
07-26 17:05:54.310: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): resource = null
07-26 17:05:54.310: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Inside if resource = null
07-26 17:05:54.310: D/CustomViewBinder(9735): Set the image view to GONE
```

The problem is that at "`Set the title view to GONE`" the "`image view`" is still set to `GONE` so the image "`Notes_Box_2_Notebook_1_006.jpg`" is not displayed - it's title is.

This is becase the "`view`" of the `CustomViewBinder` seems to always be the `ImageView` in my `XML` rather than ever being the `TextView`.

**How do I access "another" `view` in the `CustomViewBinder`?**

Comment: marienke - did you get an answer or get it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [`ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern.

I implemented it by having a `Cursor` extended class. In my main activity I get the cursor from my database helper class which queries the database. Then I link my `CustomCursorAdapter` to a [horizontal `listview`](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html) which holds three items - a `TextView` and two `ImageView`s. I then have an `OnItemClickListener` set to my horizontal `listview`. You can then filter on something, but I just updated a main `view` above my horizontal `listview` (much like in the linked tutorial).

In my `CustomCursorAdapter`'s `getView` function I define a `ViewHolder`, move the cursor to the position (from getView's parameters), andt hen do what is done in almost every example of the `getView` function, so here it is:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_media_items, null);            
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_title);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_details_resource_image);
        holder.imageviewvideo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_details_resource_video);

        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }               

    //////////////////////////TYPE      
    type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_ITEM_TYPE));
    itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_MEDIA_ITEM_ID));

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("text")){

        //////////////////////////TEXT
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_TRANSCRIPTION));
        title = title.subSequence(0, 150) + "...";
        holder.textview.setText(title);

        holder.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imageviewvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

        //////////////////////////IMAGE         
        String imageUri = "assets://";
        Log.d(TAG, "URI = " + imageUri + fileName);     

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri+fileName, holder.imageview);
        holder.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageviewvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);         
    }

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("video")){

        //////////////////////////VIDEO 
        //get the file name
        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_RESOURCE));

        //get the image of a youtube video because it's a video                                 
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Want to show video at -> http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+fileName+"/mqdefault.jpg");
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+fileName+"/mqdefault.jpg", holder.imageviewvideo);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("YouTube photo", "Failed to load photo!!! "+e.toString());
        }

        holder.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imageviewvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }       
    return convertView;     
  }
```